# Why UIPickerView shows empty list

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview

I created two `UIPickerView` and declared for each source. After click on Label user should see values for selected `UIPickerView`

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print(monthBoolLabel)
        monthPickerView.dataSource = self
        monthPickerView.delegate = self
        monthPickerView.isHidden = true

        freeDayPickerView.dataSource = self
        freeDayPickerView.delegate = self
        freeDayPickerView.isHidden = true

        let tapMonth = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tapOnMonth(gestureReconizer:)))
        monthLabel.addGestureRecognizer(tapMonth)
        monthLabel.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

        let tapFreeDay = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tapOnFreeDay(gestureReconizer:)))
        freedayLabel.addGestureRecognizer(tapFreeDay)
        freedayLabel.isUserInteractionEnabled = true


        let tapView = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(backgroundViewTapped))
        view.addGestureRecognizer(tapView)
}
```

I declared function which detect when user click on label:

```
@objc func tapOnMonth(gestureReconizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        print("*")
        monthPickerView.isHidden = false
        monthBoolLabel = true
        freedayBoolLabel = false

    }

    @objc func tapOnFreeDay(gestureReconizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        print("*")
        freeDayPickerView.isHidden = false
        freedayBoolLabel = true
        monthBoolLabel = false
    }
```

I got also extension of my `ViewController`

```
extension HomePageViewController: UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {

    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        if freedayBoolLabel == true {
            return freeDaySource.count
        }
        else if monthBoolLabel == true{
            return monthSource.count
        }
        else {
            return 0
        }
    }


    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        if freedayBoolLabel == true {
            freedayLabel.text = freeDaySource[row]
        }
        else if monthBoolLabel == true{
            monthLabel.text = monthSource[row]
        }

    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        if freedayBoolLabel == true {
            return freeDaySource[row]
        }
        else if monthBoolLabel == true{
            return monthSource[row]
        }
        else {
            return ""
        }
    }

}
```

No matter at which `UILabel` user click, lists always are empty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to reload the picker view after tapping on a label.

```
@objc func tapOnMonth(gestureReconizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    print("*")
    monthPickerView.isHidden = false
    monthBoolLabel = true
    freedayBoolLabel = false
    monthPickerView.reloadAllComponents() // add this
}
```

Make a similar change in the other one too.

FYI - you only need one picker view, not two, since you are only showing one at a time anyway.

Comment: Thank You so much, I will change it

Comment: I have one more question, if I would like to have in same `ViewController` `UIDatePicker` and `UIPickerView` is it possible to do?

Comment: I've already add, but could you tell me, need I add another picker view to my `ViewController`?

Comment: Add whatever controls you need. If you need help with another issue, feel free to post a question specific to your new issue. Be sure to include all relevant details about what you tried and what help you need.

Comment: Ok, Thank You one more time